# How to change virtual devices path of Genymotion?

Tags: path, virtual, device, genymotion

Genymotion generally stores the virtual devices in some particular place.  For instance in Windows they are in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Genymobile\`.  There doesn't seem to be any way of setting this path.

I want to move the virtual devices to another drive, how can I do this?

Answer (score 17):

I have the same problem , and I didn't find any solution to this and what is the most important is that I solve it myself . below is my solution :
(system  Win7 x64)
**firstly you should change Virtual Device Setting path ( Genymotion --> Settings --> VirtualBox --> Browse) and close your genymotion software.**
step 1: move C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Genymobile to your desire path.
step 2: now you can delete the file about Genymobile.
step 3: double click {your path }/Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\Samsung Galaxy Note - 4.1.1 - API 16 - 800x1280/ ***.vbox file and wait until a Oracle VM VirtualBox window pop .
Edit: You may get an error saying that an other device with same UUID exists.In this case, right click the old ones, remove them and redo step 3. 
step 4:open genymotion,and you will see a new record in list.

steps above is my solution.

and this solution just works to those have been deployed before.

Comment: thanks, worked for me.

Comment: Also works on mac. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks - worked on win 10 1803 - great job!!

Comment: Made my day. Tks

Comment: it's not working (Genymotion 3.0.*), I see devices in the list but they won't start https://i.postimg.cc/Ls104CPW/Screenshot-1.png

Comment: Genymotion support just told me that this method is outdated. They recommend that you use VirtualBox' export and import feature to move virtual devices.

Answer (score 0):

Testing with GenyMotion 2.2.0 the image files are now downloaded into:

C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\ova
To re-use the downloaded images on a another machine without downloading them again:

Copy the desired image file(s) to the ova folder on the second machine.
Restart GenyMotion.
Create a new device matching the version of the image you copied over.
GenyMotion will warn that the new version will be downloaded.
Click next (don't tick the option to use cached files).
GenyMotion should create the new device without downloading the image.
Update - potential problems:

Version of Genymotion and the virtual device are different:

If you receive this error message:

Open VirtualBox
Right-click your Genymotion virtual device and select Settings
Select the System section
Check that the Acceleration tab is not dimmed and that the VT-x/AMD-v and Nested Paging options are enabled
If not: try enabling virtualization in your PC's BIOS.

Comment: The question is about moving files to another drive within the same machine. Not to migrate them to another machine.

Comment: Also the question is about the virtual devices not the downloaded images

Comment: @flurbius I don't know if you know that Genymotion runs virtual device's image using virtual box which means image is virtual device itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but Im using a Gnu+Linux distribution (deepin (based on debian) but this should work for most distros).

I found the AVDs stored under ~/.android/avd/ possibly this location is because I have Android Studio installed. I moved them to /desired-path/.android/avd and created an environment variable called $ANDROID_AVD_HOME set to /desired-path/.android.

eg assuming /data is on the file system you want the AVDs and you want them in /data/android-stuff/.android then open a shell and issue the following commands

```
mkdir -p /data/android-stuff/.android
cd /data/android-stuff/.android
mv -a ~/.android/avd ./
```

then edit your ~/.profile or ~/.zshenv file to include this line

```
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/data/android-stuff/.android
```